# Resizing/rescaling head

Tags: modeling, camera, scale

I’m very new to blender and I was watching a good tutorial on how to make an anime like model (I’m only making a head). But I missed a step in the beginning and forgot to scale/size it to a normal head size. I tried rescaling it to 0.127 on all axis as was shown in the beginning of the tutorial①, applying all transformations + rotation and scale. But when I want to zoom in on the model or move the view it becomes very slow to impossible to move. I definitely missed something. After trail and error, the head is already perfect and I don’t want to f up. I’m currently on the unwrapping part of tutorial② and I realized (or assuming) that I can’t use the same units the tutorial person is using to make the skin cause my head is huge. Please help me.

References:
①first part of tutorial where I forgot to scale: https://youtu.be/5JA0f8ZgIw0 (3:08)
②Where I am currently at with the unwrapping: https://youtu.be/9GvXGfewfL0 (17:29)

Comment: What if you just select the head and go to View->Frame Selected? Does that fix the zoom speed?

Comment: better not use youtube links or links that are not permanent / internal to StackExchange. Now regarding your question, did you try to re-frame your viewport (after selecting the head) by pressing the (Del"." on numpad) ?